# BitmapEncoder FlushAsync() never returns in Xamarin UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion, xamarin.uwp

I am converting png to Jpeg using this code but it is getting stuck on encoder.FlushAsync() and never returns. I have tried several ways to resolve this but nothing works. encoder.FlushAsync() doesn't even give exceptions. Without await debug gets passed but the image is not correct and with await, application freezed. I have mentioned the link and code below:

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7918/how-to-convert-jpeg-image-from-png-image-and-draw-those-jpeg-image-into-pdf-document

```
public async Task<Stream> ConvertPngToJpeg2(Stream s)
{
         byte[] resultArray = null;
            
         //Convert stream into byte array
         byte[] image = new byte[s.Length];
         s.Read(image, 0, image.Length);
           
         //Create An Instance of WriteableBitmap object  
         WriteableBitmap resultBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
 
         using (IRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
          {
              await ms.WriteAsync(image.AsBuffer());
              ms.Seek(0);
                
               //Set the source for WriteableBitmap  
               resultBitmap.SetSource(ms);
          }
 
        //Get the image data
        using (IRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
         {
             try
              {
                  byte[] bytes;
 
                  // Open a stream to copy the image contents to the WriteableBitmap's pixel buffer
                  using (Stream stream = resultBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
                  {
                      bytes = new byte[(uint)stream.Length];
                      await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                  }
 
                 // Create an encoder with the Jpeg format
                 BitmapEncoder encoder = await   BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, ms);
                   
                 // WriteableBitmap uses BGRA format 
                 encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)resultBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)resultBitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, bytes);
 
                 //Terminate the encoder bytes
                 await encoder.FlushAsync();
                    
                 resultArray = new byte[ms.AsStream().Length];
                 await ms.AsStream().ReadAsync(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
             }
         }
 
         //Store the image into memory stream
         Stream imgStream = new MemoryStream(resultArray);
 
        //Return the Jpeg image as stream
        return imgStream;
 }
```

gone through some links:
[BitmapEncoder FlushAsync() never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905460/bitmapencoder-flushasync-never-returns)
[BitmapEncoder FlushAsync throws Argument Exception - c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332153/bitmapencoder-flushasync-throws-argument-exception-c-sharp)

Comment: *"with await, application freezed"*  "Freeze when use await" may mean UI MainThread is "deadlocked". Search for previous threads about freezes with await.

Answer (score 0):

We have attached the runnable sample for your reference. Please try this on your end and let us know the result.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/UWP_Sample-1957906502